# PropertyChanged.Fody - Conflict between solutions using version 1 and 2

Tags: fody-propertychanged

I have two distinct solution using PropertyChanged.Fody. There were both on `version 1`. Then I upgraded one solution to `version 2`. Since, the solution on `version 1` shows error like that:

> Error     Fody: Could not load 'ModuleWeaver' from 'PropertyChanged.Fody,
>   Version=2.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' due to
>   ReflectionTypeLoadException.
>
> It is possible you need to update the package.
>   exception.LoaderExceptions: System.IO.FileLoadException: The located
>   assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I'm lost as the solution with version 1 has absolutely no reference to `PropertyChanged.Fody 2.1.2.0.`

Comment: See github issue and workaround: https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged/issues/261#issuecomment-312564704